# How to get handle of last element of tree in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

There's a table in which td has different level amount of html within them. How to get to last tag/element in tree? For example the following code does not show the text inside last element (if it was `<span>, <div>, <li>` or what ever).

```
let tabletd = await document.body.querySelectorAll('table td');
await tabletd.forEach (async tditem => {
  let lastElement= await tditem.querySelector ('*:last-child');
  let textOfLastTag= lastElement.innerText;
  console.log(textOfLastTag);
}
```

Comment: Are all nodes in the `td` leafs? Or are there trees inside each node?

Comment: the trees are all inside their onw td's. Some td has like
`
<div>
 <div>
   <div>
    text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
`

While others `<span>`
or `<ul><li></li></ul>` etc

Comment: Keep in mid this is only picking up the first element which is a last child. The CSS query works I've test it but you must be doing something wrong with `puppeteer`. Also, is this `console.log` printing on the browser? (e.g. in an `evaluate` maybe?)

Comment: actually I got it work with those selectors, not sure what was wrong before Partly could have been that picking the first of the last items. Console log was printing to browser (was running it inside evaluate).